# onmouseclick function javascript/html

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling, onmouseclick

I'm trying to implement an event handler for a button to change an element's content
and I have this just as a sort of test to make sure things work, and they do. However, I'd assume that once I refreshen the page, the original content that the element "**generatedMeal**" had would reappear, it does not. How would I get my "default" text to reappear upon refreshing?

```js
const button=document.getElementById("generateButton");
const textField= document.getElementById("generatedMeal");

function changeText(){
    textField.innerHTML="hello";
}
button.onmouseclick=changeText();
```

Comment: Instead of writing button.onmouseclick , try using button.onclikck, it should work

Answer (score 0):

this should do the trick

```
    const button=document.getElementById("generateButton");
const textField= document.getElementById("generatedMeal");

function changeText(){
    textField.innerHTML="hello";
}

document.getElementById('generateButton').addEventListener('click', changeText)
```

If you post your html code I could probably tell you why it didn't work. Cheers

Comment: Thank you!  this did the trick. now I have to find out the difference between the two as clearly I mixed them up...